# How to call python script from CasperJS

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to call a python script from within CasperJS and grab the output from python.

```
casp = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casp.start().then(function() {
  var cp = require('child_process');
    cp.execFile('/usr/bin/python','test.py', {},function(_,stdout,stderr){
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
});

casp.run();
```

test.py is just `print "hello world"` atm for testing, but this script when I run it just exits without running the python.

If I replace the test.py arg with --version, e.g.

`cp.execFile('/usr/bin/python','--version', {},function(_,stdout,stderr){`

Then I get the version information correctly. I think it must be an issue with how arguments are passed in execFile, but not sure what I should be doing.

Comment: did you update the path in casperjs.cmd or somewhere else?

Comment: nope, haven't made any changes to casperjs, fresh download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you exit prematurely. An empty `casper.run()` means that it will exit as soon as all `casper` steps are executed. The child_process module is not a CasperJS module (it's provided by PhantomJS) so it cannot know that it is executing.

You could either simply use

```js
casp.run(function(){});
```

to prevent the exiting. But then you will probably need to kill the CasperJS process.

A better way would be to set a variable when the execution finished and continue only then:

```js
casp.start().then(function() {
  var finished = false;
  var cp = require('child_process');
  cp.execFile('/usr/bin/python','test.py', {},function(_,stdout,stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    finished = true;
  });
  this.waitFor(function check(){
    return finished;
  }, function then(){
    // can stay empty
  });
}).run();
```

If you want to pass multiple arguments to the external program, you should use an array as the second argument to [`execFile`](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/)